# React/Webpack site suddenly loses CSS

Tags: reactjs, webpack, material-ui, css-loader, jss

I'm building a site with React/Node/Express/Webpack/Material-UI.

It's something to do with JSS ... Using `run dev` works, but after `build`ing, when I click some buttons with `onClick` actions, all my custom CSS styling just disappears, and being replaced by many wrong `.jss` rules.

How do I track down this bug?

Here's my `webpack.config`:

```
const path = require('path');
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
const CleanWebpackPlugin = require('clean-webpack-plugin');

const outputDirectory = 'dist';

module.exports = {
    entry: ['babel-polyfill', './src/client/client.js'],
    output: {
        path: path.join(__dirname, outputDirectory),
        filename: 'bundle.js'
    },
    module: {
        rules: [{
            test: /\.(js|jsx)$/,
            exclude: /node_modules/,
            use: {
                loader: 'babel-loader'
            }
        },
        {
            test: /\.css$/,
            use: ['style-loader', 'css-loader']
        },
        {
            test: /\.(png|woff|woff2|eot|ttf|svg)$/,
            loader: 'url-loader?limit=100000'
        }
        ]
    },
    resolve: {
        extensions: ['*', '.js', '.jsx']
    },
    devServer: {
        port: 3000,
        proxy: {
            '/api': 'http://localhost:8080'
        }
    },
    plugins: [
        new CleanWebpackPlugin([outputDirectory]),
        new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
            template: './public/index.html',
            favicon: './public/favicon.ico'
        })
    ]
};
```

And `.babelrc`:

```
{
  "presets": [
    "@babel/preset-env",
    "@babel/preset-react"
  ],
  "plugins": [
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties"
  ]
}
```

JSS stuff in `client.js`:

```
import { create } from 'jss';
import rtl from 'jss-rtl';
import JssProvider from 'react-jss/lib/JssProvider';
import { createGenerateClassName, jssPreset } from '@material-ui/core/styles';
const jss = create({ plugins: [...jssPreset().plugins, rtl()] });
const generateClassName = createGenerateClassName();
const theme = createMuiTheme({
    direction: 'rtl',
....
});

function RTL(props) {
    return (
        <JssProvider jss={jss} generateClassName={generateClassName}>
            {props.children}
        </JssProvider>
    );
}

function Root() {
    return (
        <RTL>
            <MuiThemeProvider theme={theme}>
                <App />
            </MuiThemeProvider>
        </RTL>
    );
}

render(<Root />, document.querySelector('#root'));
```

Answer (score 1):

You could try using the [postcss-loader](https://github.com/postcss/postcss-loader) like I did in my app:

```
{
  test: /\.css$/,
  exclude: /node_modules/,
  use: [
    { loader: 'style-loader' },
    {
      loader: 'css-loader',
      options: {
        importLoaders: 1,
        modules: true,
        localIdentName: '[name]__[local]__[hash:base64:5]'
      }
    },
    {
      loader: 'postcss-loader',
      options: {
        ident: 'postcss',
        plugins: () => [
          autoprefixer({
            browsers: [
              "> 1%",
              "last 2 versions"
            ]
          })
        ]
      }
    }
  ]
},
```

And if you are not going to do anything fancy or specific with your `webpack` configuration, you could also use the `react run build` provided when you create your app with [`react-create-app`](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app), their build configuration are based on `webpack` and it's result are pretty satisfatory.

Comment: Unfortunately that doesn't work because I'm using the airbnb datepicker which requires style-loader :(